# how are GUIDs generated in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, guid

How are GUIDs generated in SQL Server?

I understand that I should use `newid()`, but what is the algorithm that function uses? Is it a hash of the time/date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm to create it is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier

> **Algorithm**
>
> In the OSF-specified algorithm for generating new (V1) GUIDs, the
>   user's network card MAC address is used as a base for the last group
>   of GUID digits, which means, for example, that a document can be
>   tracked back to the computer that created it. This privacy hole was
>   used when locating the creator of the Melissa worm[2]. Most of the
>   other digits are based on the time while generating the GUID. V1 GUIDs
>   which contain a MAC address and time can be identified by the digit
>   "1" in the first position of the third group of digits, for example
>   {2f1e4fc0-81fd-11da-9156-00036a0f876a}. V4 GUIDs use the later
>   algorithm, which is a pseudo-random number. These have a "4" in the
>   same position, for example {38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0}.
>   More specifically, the 'data3' bit pattern would be 0001xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   in the first case, and 0100xxxxxxxxxxxx in the second. Cryptanalysis
>   of the WinAPI GUID generator shows that, since the sequence of V4
>   GUIDs is pseudo-random; given full knowledge of the internal state, it
>   is possible to predict previous and subsequent values