# SQL Server 2008 GUID generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, guid, entropy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how are GUIDs generated in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242287/how-are-guids-generated-in-sql-server)

I wonder how SQL Server 2008 GUIDs are generated? Entropy bits

Comment: It was, yes. See http://blog.cloudflare.com/why-google-went-offline-today-and-a-bit-about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the GUID:-

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

You can refer [How GUI generation works](http://www.webdav.org/specs/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt)