# Guid.NewGuid(); behind the scenes in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, uuid, guid

Researching the subject yesterday, I found several interesting questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366368/does-uuidcreate-use-a-csprng)) on how GUIDs are ultimately generated. In brief; it seems that `Guid.NewGuid();` calls `CoCreateGuid` in the COM, which in turn calls `UuidCreate` in the Windows RPC (docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568(VS.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx)).

I found myself wondering; How does this work when the OS is *not* Windows, such as might be the case with .NET Core, and does this affect the ['version' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) used to generate the GUID (which I understand is Version 4 on Windows)?

Comment: You check how Mono does it here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Guid.cs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On non-windows machines, .NET Core will use either [`uuid_create`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uuid_create) on BSD (which is "version 1") or libuuid's [`uuid_generate_random`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_generate_random) function on macOS and linux ("version 4").

The implementation for the replacement `CoCreateGuid` function can be found in [CoreCLR's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/pal/src/misc/miscpalapi.cpp#L355).

Comment: `nm libcoreclr.dylib | grep uuid` (macOS) says that it calls `uuid_generate_random`; which is a v4 GUID.  `uuid_create` must be a macro somewhere on that platform.

Comment: sry yes macOS also uses the other function, I assumed it aligned to BSD here. A quick check tells me macOS indeed ships a `<uuid/uuid.h>` header with `uuid_generate_random` being provided by `libSystem.B.dylib`